# Is it possible to integrate apache ranger/atlas with apache flink?

Tags: apache-flink, apache-ranger, apache-atlas

Flink is great at what it does and the flink sql client looks very promising. I'm trying to understand if it would be possible to integrate governance tools with flink sql client when used for interactive queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported, but it has recently been discussed in the community and the integration is work in progress. [1]

[1] http://apache-flink-mailing-list-archive.1008284.n3.nabble.com/Discussion-Job-generation-submission-hooks-Atlas-integration-tp37298.html